# Why is my aspx designer file referencing user controls incorrectly?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following user controls (for now, more will go in the same namespace)

```
Ortund.Project.UserControls.FooControl
Ortund.Project.UserControls.BarControl
```

I've referenced these correctly in my web.config (I know this I have got these controls to work correctly on the page).

```
<pages>
    <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="ortund" tagName="Foo" src="~/UserControls/FooControl.ascx" />
        <add tagPrefix="ortund" tagName="Bar" src="~/UserControls/BarControl.ascx" />
    </controls>
</pages>
```

This allows me to use the controls in my markup as follows:

```
<div>
    <ortund:Foo runat="server" ID="oFoo" />
    <ortund:Bar runat="server" ID="oBar" />
</div>
```

At least, it would if the Designer file for the page correctly referenced them on the above-mentioned namespace.

Instead, what I find in my designer file is this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// oFoo control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Auto-generated field.
    /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
    /// </remarks>
    protected global::System.Web.UI.UserControl oFoo;

    /// <summary>
    /// oBar control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Auto-generated field.
    /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
    /// </remarks>
    protected global::System.Web.UI.UserControl oBar;
```

Now, I can go in and change it, but since the file is auto-generated, it tends to just change back again for no apparent reason. As a result, I'm not able to access any public fields I may have in the user control which is a major problem for functionality.

So why is my designer file so blatantly and so stupidly wrong then and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience with `UserControl`s misbehaving, it's usually because you've got something "weird" with the namespace of your controls, or there's an inheritance hierarchy that Visual Studio can't get its head around, or, you're doing something in a `web.config` that is below the application level (though this usually results in bits of the namespace being chopped off and the .designer.cs refusing to compile).

I've just created a "simple" reproduction of your case above and the designer gets the declaration right as:

```
protected global::Ortund.Project.UserControls.FooControl oFoo;
```

One option you have is to act on the comment immediately above the declaration ("To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.") and move the declaration from the .designer.cs file into the .cs file. This *may* stop the designer regenerating an incorrect declaration, although the fact that it's already doing so may mean that there's something sufficiently *wrong* that it'll keep on doing it, despite your best efforts.

More information about your solution/project structure and the inheritance hierarchy (if any) for your UserControls and pages may help to narrow this down!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know what other information to provide, however, I can confirm that having moved those field declarations to my code-behind file has resolved the problem.

Comment: @Ortund, it's a work around, I know, but at least it unblocks you =) A couple of things to check (a) Is your <pages> declaration in your application level web.config? (b) Do you have a web.config in any of the folders between there and the the folder that contains the page, that's perhaps modifying/clearing the <pages> section? (c) Do you have any other classes with the same name? I've seen all of the above cause weirdness before =(